# $cookies.get doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies

So, I have a site using cookies with login. Once someone is logged I want some elements to appear and disappear. At the moment nothing happens. It's showing all the time. Looks like sid is always empty.
ngCookies ver. 1.4.8

Html code:

```
<img ng-init="checklogin()" ng-hide="sid" src="./images/sits_large_noborder.png" ng-click="auth()"/>
```

Controller:

```
.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', 'Auth', '$location', '$cookies', function ($scope, Auth, $location, $cookies) {
        $scope.sid = null;
        $scope.checklogin = function () {
            $scope.sid = $cookies.get('sid');
        }
```

Comment: can you replace `$cookies.get('sid')` by `true` to see if the rest is working as expected? If yes, then `console.log($scope.sid)` after you get the value to check what's wrong.

Comment: @floribon If i change it to true it is working.
Console log says undefined.

Comment: So you could rewrite your whole question into why `$cookies.get` doesn't give you what you expect. I never tried them so I cannot answer you but the rest of the question is useless

Comment: You're right. I will do that

Comment: Does the cookie appear in `document.cookie`?

Comment: @AtesGoral Where? I know the cookies are there and I have sid as well while inspecting my browser

Comment: To clarify: Are you seeing the cookie when you type `document.cookie` in the console, or are you just looking at the HTTP response header?

Comment: ng-init will only run checklogin once on load. Does the auth() function also call checklogin? Otherwise the value of sid will never change and the img will remain visible.

Comment: @AtesGoral document.cookie in console shows only one thing - time, not the sid I am looking for. Is this the issue? When I browse through developer tools or postman I see the other cookies as well.

Comment: @kasia I tried with calling checklogin inside auth but it doesn't matter. It always shows as undefined.

Comment: @NotAJohnDoe That's potentially the issue. Try setting the cookie path to "/" when setting it on the server side. Also make sure you're not using HTTP-only cookies. If you don't see your cookie in `document.cookie`, there's really no way for the poor $cookies service to read it either :)

Comment: AG has a point. I had the same issue until I explicitly set path to / when I got caught up on ng versions. Never needed to do that pre 1.4.

Comment: @kasia I made it work with a temporary version. Cookie was a http one. I made another one and it is working now :). Thanks for all your help!